# Combining a source event and error event using RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm using an API from a Cordova plugin (https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) in Ionic that allows you to subscribe to events like so:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (loc) => {
  // Handle location
});

BackgroundGeolocation.on('error', (error) => {
  // Handle error
});
```

I'm trying to wrap this interface into a single Observable so that I can subscribe to it the regular way and get updates:

```
source.subscribe((loc) => {
  // handle location
}, (err) => {
  // handle error
})
```

How can I do this?

I've tried using [`fromEventPattern`](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/bridging_to_events.html#bridging-to-custom-events-with-fromeventpattern) and I can get the 'location' event like below but I'm not sure how to add in the errors as well.

```
const source = fromEventPattern(
  function addHandler(h) {
    return BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => {
      h(location);
    });
  }, function delHandler(h, signal) {
    signal.remove();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take is to just use `Observable.create`.  Here is a StackBlitz demo (https://jsfiddle.net/4eLuvhkp/).  For your code it would be something like...

```
const source = Observable.create(subscriber => {
  BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => {
    subscriber.next(location);
  });
  BackgroundGeolocation.on('error', (error) => {
    subscriber.error(error);
  });
  return () => {
    signal.remove();
  };
});
```

It might just be `create` and not `Observable.create` depending on your import style.

EDIT: Added unsubscribe handler.

Comment: Admittedly I don't know RxJS very well, but wouldn't that create and register a new event handler with BackgroundGeolocation every time there was a new subscriber?

Comment: Yes.  Although `fromEventPattern` will also do that.  The key thing you want here is called "multicasting" (or sometimes colloquially "sharing") and the `publish` operator is what you want although it requires some extra work to handle when you `connect` / `disconnect`.  A good introduction might be [here](https://blog.jonstodle.com/dont-do-extra-work-use-publish/)